# Dropdown menu issue in IPAD browsers

Tags: ios, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have an issue in IPAD browsers(Chrome and Safari) like when i click on dropdown menu the values are hiding inside the table section.
Here i am attaching the image .[image]

I have used `z-index` attribute but still the issue is not fixed.

Here is my code for Table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped m-b-none text-small b-b" id="eventListTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="width:2% !important;"></th>
                <th width="15%"></th>               
                <th width="10%"></th> 
                <th width="10%"></th>

                   <th width="10%"></th>

                   <th width="10%"></th>


                <th width="10%"></th>

                <th width="10%"></th>               
                <th width="10%"></th>

                <th width="10%"></th>

                <th width="30%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Code for table data `<td>` and dropdown is inside the table.:

```
<td> <input type='checkbox' id='eventCheckBox' value=''></td>
<td width="20%" class="wrap-sm"><a class="dropdown-toggle h5"
    data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="eventName" ></a>
    <small class="block"></small>
    <h6><span class="label label-info"></span></h6>
</td>

<td width="8%"><h5></h5></td>
<td width="10%"><h5><a href="#" id="registeredCount" title="></a></h5></td>
<td width="9%"><h5><a href="#" id="checkedInCount"></a></h5></td>
<td width="12%"><h5></h5></td>

<td width="15%"><h5><small class="label bg-light"></small></h5></td>
<td width="15%"><h5><small class="label bg-light"></small></h5></td>

<td width="10%" align="center" style="padding-top:20px">
<i class="icon-circle text-success"></i></td>
<td style="padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="btn-group dropup AttendeeDropDown">
            <img src="images/icon-add-attendee.png" alt="Add Attendee" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-122px;">
                <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="NewAttendee"> Create New Attendee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="ExistingAttendee">Add Existing Attendee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="Import">Import</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="Export">Export</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

Code for dropdown inside the table.

     <div class="btn-group dropup AttendeeDropDown">
                <img src="images/icon-add-attendee.png" alt="Add Attendee" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-122px;">
                    <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="NewAttendee"> Create New Attendee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="ExistingAttendee">Add Existing Attendee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="Import">Import</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="addAttendeeBtn" data-value="Export">Export</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I am using bootstrap.css for my application..

How to show the dropdown over the table is it possible with css or using any script?

Comment: Absolute positioning of the dropdown should resolve the issue, if you're happy to go down that route? Where is the dropdown code placed inside the table? Is it intended to be displayed within the table boundaries?

Comment: @Graham,I Have added entire code now and also tried with the absolute positioning of the dropdown but if i do it the last dropdown is getting merged.